# MongoDB Scala Driver doesn't allow use Map collection in case class

Tags: mongodb, scala

I just started using MongoDB and I'm trying to write a small application to test Mongo with Scala. I created the following case class in order to cast the Documents to a Scala class:

```
case class User(
                 _id: ObjectId,
                 userId: String,
                 items: Map[String, Int]
               )

object User {
  def apply(userId: String , items: Map[String, Int]): User =
    new User(new ObjectId, userId, items)

  implicit val codecRegistry: CodecRegistry = 
    fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[User]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)
}
```

I get the following error but I don't know why since the Map keys are in fact strings.

```
[ERROR] error: Maps must contain string types for keys
[INFO]   implicit val codecRegistry: CodecRegistry = fromRegistries (fromProviders (classOf [User]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)
[INFO]                                                                                      ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

I'm also applying the `codecRegistry` to the MongoDatabase.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the driver?

Comment: The official driver https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a version of the driver that is compiled for Scala 2.11 and not 2.12. By changing the Maven dependency from

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb.scala</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongo-scala-driver_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb.scala</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongo-scala-driver_2.12</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

solved the problem.